# Remote Process Execution

Tags: c#, .net, process, remote-access

My scenerio is connection to remote machine with C#.Net, and listing all processes with that remote computer. I can kill a process, or start a new process at remote. The problem is, when I execute a new process on remote, I can see the process on task manager, but it doesnt apeear on windows screen. Any idea why its not appearing on windows, but appearing on task manager/ process. Here is my execution code

```
private void btnStartNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object[] arrParams = { txtNewProcess.Text.Trim()};
        try
        {
            manageClass = new ManagementClass(myScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
            manageClass.InvokeMethod("Create", arrParams);
            btnConnect_Click(sender, e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My Scope is :

```
myScope = new ManagementScope(@"\ROOT\CIMV2", connOptions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is about administrator permissions

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the ManagementPath be something like \ComputerName\Root\CIMV2 instead of just \ROOT\CIMV2 ?

Comment: connOptions manage this. Think, I am in the computer. So I dont need type a computer name. Its working, just the problem is cant see the .exe which I started in UI

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with authentication, then you need to check the DCOM configuration on the target machine.

1. On the target machine, run `dcomcnfg` from the command prompt.
2. Expand `Component Services\Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config`
3. Find Windows Management Instruction, identified with GUID `8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820` (you can see this in the details view).
4. Edit the properties and then add the username you are trying to login with under the permissions tab.
5. You may need to reboot the service for the changes to take effect.